# css width -width of item (automatically)

Tags: css

I currently have the below CSS style:

```
.center480
{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -240px;
}
```

this, is fine for anything with the width of 480px. The thing is, i want the margin-left, to be dynamic so that it works like the center tag, which can center something in this way.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it may have [less browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), you could use the `translateX`/`translateY` method.

- **Horizontally and vertical centering:**

  - Method 1 [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/n94L33hj/)

    ```
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
    ```
  - Method 2 [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/myyxxh9q/)

    ```
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        top:0; right:0;
        bottom:0; left:0;
        margin:auto;
    }
    ```
- **Horizontal centering:**

  - Approach 1: [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/jm4n6ud6/)

    ```
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    ```
  - Approach 2: [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dnnohwe/)

    ```
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
    ```
- **Vertical centering:**

  - Approach 1: [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6ne47jw/)

    ```
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    ```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i cannot use position:absolute. This, because of the responsiveness.

Comment: @MichelKok You can still use `position: absolute` in responsive design. You just have to use it right. In most cases, you should just be absolutely positioning elements relative to parent elements.

Comment: @MichelKok You could also try `translateX(-50%)` with `position: relative`, that may work.

Answer (score 0):

transform: translateX(-50%); In combination with my existing CSS, did the trick. :)